# Java "this"-keyword marked as static in eclipse content assist

Tags: java, eclipse, static, this

Does anybody know the reason why the `this` keyword (Java) is marked as `static final` in the content assist in Eclipse? `final` makes sense to me, but why `static`?

[image: Screenshot Eclipse]

The screenshot was made with Eclipse 2020-03, but I'm observing this behavior since many years.

Comment: Very interesting question. :) +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code doing this is in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuesser`

```
// add 'this'
if (currentType != null && !(fEnclosingElement instanceof IMethod && Flags.isStatic(((IMethod) fEnclosingElement).getFlags()))) {
  String fullyQualifiedName= currentType.getFullyQualifiedName('.');
  if (fullyQualifiedName.equals(expectedType)) {
    ImageDescriptor desc= new JavaElementImageDescriptor(JavaPluginImages.DESC_FIELD_PUBLIC, JavaElementImageDescriptor.FINAL | JavaElementImageDescriptor.STATIC, JavaElementImageProvider.SMALL_SIZE);
    res.add(new Variable(fullyQualifiedName, "this", Variable.LITERALS, false, res.size(), new char[] {'.'}, desc));  //$NON-NLS-1$
  }
}
```

The key thing in that code is

```
JavaElementImageDescriptor.FINAL | JavaElementImageDescriptor.STATIC
```

as the flags to `JavaElementImageDescriptor` which is hard coding the display of the static and final overlay images. So these are always displayed for `this`.

As to why that was chosen the code doesn't give any reason.

Comment: Thank you very much, interesting! I wonder why they chose this approach. Do you see any logical reason to consider `this` as static?

Comment: No, I can't think of a reason. It doesn't seem to make sense to me and I don't see anything in the Java Language Specification. You could try reporting this as a bug in Eclipse Bugzilla (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs)

Comment: @greg-449 Nice answer. I didn't know this. +1

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons. 1) `this` can not be reassigned and 2) you're inside a constructor and not a normal method.

Comment: IMHO your first point is a reason for `final`, not for `static`. And concerning your second point: Actually I'm inside an initializer, not inside a constructor. But this is not relevant anyway, because the content assist shows the same behavior in initializers, constructors, and normal methods.